# В форме MS Access есть ListBox, не обрабатываются события Click и DblClick

Tags: vba, ms-access

Есть форма в MS Access, на которой есть элемент Список. Хочу сделать чтобы по одинарному щелчку мыши (Click) высвечивалась дополнительная информация в другом поле, а по двойному щелчку мыши (DblClick) открывалась другая форма. Когда есть оба эти события в коде VBA, то DblClick не выполняется, вместо него выполняется событие Click. Как разделить эти два события? Предполагаю что дело в тайминге нажатия кнопки мыши.

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

> Когда есть оба эти события в коде VBA, то DblClick не выполняется, вместо него выполняется событие Click.

Согласно встроенной справке

> For objects that receive mouse events, the events occur in this order:
>
> **MouseDown → MouseUp → Click → DblClick**
>
> When you double-click a command button (command button: A control that runs a macro, calls a Visual Basic function, or runs an event procedure. This is sometimes called a push button in other applications.), the following events occur in this order:
>
> **MouseDown → MouseUp → Click → DblClick → MouseUp → Click**

Допускаю, что Вы в каком-то обработчике кодом "обрубаете" цепочку эвентов...

Comment: В том то и дело, насколько я понимаю согласно этой цепочке при двойном нажатии кнопки мыши вначале выполняется просто Click а уже затем DblClick. А мне необходимо разделить эти события, чтобы при DblClick не выполнялся вначале Click

Comment: Ну это Вам надо будет написАть свой листбокс... или как вариант в Click запоминать предыдущее состояние того самого "другого поля", и в DblClick "отменять" работу Click, возвращая предыдущее состояние.

Comment: Если честно, то ничего не понял.. Код который написан в DblClick никогда не выполняется, т.к. его перехватывает событие Click. Поэтому выполнить то что вы написали невозможно. И что значит написать свой листбокс?

Comment: Не выдумывать себе головной боли и  назначить вторую процедуру на правый клик. Или разнести события на разные элементы формы

Comment: Я уже и так разнес на правый клик второе событие, но просто хочется решить этот вопрос на будущее) Плюс непонятно почему так "убого" это сделано в Access, интересно в чем причина этого.